# How to iterate over a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of lists, for example,

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

with an even length. Like a square of pixels where black is 1 and white is 0, like a chessboard.

And  I want a function that will return 4 lists:

- The first list is 2x2 lower right corner would be  a list with `[1,1,0,0]`
- The second list is 2x2 upper right corner would be a list with `[1,1,0,0]`
- The third list is 2x2 lower left corner would be a list with  `[0,0,1,1]`
- The forth list is 2x2 upper left corner would be a list with  `[1,1,0,0]`

I don't quite yet know how to do this. I expect to receive the 4 lists described above.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me from the description what the desired algorithm is to produce the output.

Comment: I have a chessBoard, which is represented as a list of lists. I want to divide that chessboard into four the upper and lower right corner, the upper and lower left corner, which would be four lists that store each corner. I want a function that returns the 4 lists.

Answer (score 3):

The following is working for me, assuming I have now understood your requirements. There may be more sophisticated ways to do this, but this is a simple one which isn't too painful - the key is to write general functions which can take the first/second half of a list of even length. Then the functions you want are built simply from them:

```
firstHalf :: [a] -> [a]
firstHalf xs
    | odd n = error "list needs to have even length"
    | otherwise = take h xs
    where n = length xs
          h = n `div` 2

secondHalf :: [a] -> [a]
secondHalf xs
    | odd n = error "list needs to have even length"
    | otherwise = drop h xs
    where n = length xs
          h = n `div` 2

topLeftCorner :: [[a]] -> [a]
topLeftCorner = concatMap firstHalf . firstHalf

topRightCorner :: [[a]] -> [a]
topRightCorner = concatMap secondHalf . firstHalf

bottomLeftCorner :: [[a]] -> [a]
bottomLeftCorner = concat . reverse . map firstHalf . secondHalf

bottomRightCorner :: [[a]] -> [a]
bottomRightCorner = concat . reverse . map secondHalf . secondHalf

allCorners :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
allCorners board = [bottomRightCorner, topRightCorner, bottomLeftCorner, topLeftCorner] <*> [board]
```

examples of using it, first for your input and then a 6x6 example:

```
*Main>let board = [[1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0], [1 ,1, 0,0] , [0, 0, 1,1]]                                              
*Main> allCorners board
[[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0]]
*Main> let board = [[1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [1 ,1, 0,0,1,1] , [0, 0, 1,1,0,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
*Main>allCorners board                                                                                           
[[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]]
```

As often in functional programming (and indeed in programming in general), the best way to approach a more complex problem is to break it down into smaller ones.

Comment: It can be done much more concisely if you imagine choosing the first or second half nondeterministically. So: ```topBottom xs = let (l, r) = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs in [l,r]; leftRight = transpose . map topBottom; corners = leftRight >=> topBottom```. You can toss a `map concat` on at the end if it seems really necessary to throw away that extra structure, but I suspect it's more useful to keep it anyway.

Comment: thanks, that's a nice approach. (I didn't even realise there was a `transpose` function in the standard libraries!)